# OpenERP and Gunicorn

Tags: cron, wsgi, odoo, gunicorn

Is possible to have a more specific configuration for openerp 6.1 and gunicorn?
I'm interested to run openerp on wsgi web server and I'm interested to have a more detailed information about the cron task management :)
There is poor documentation on the web.

Comment: I would like to know too,.  its taking too long do this simple configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at http://thu.openerp.com/open-days-2012/gunicorn.html

Edit: he references the openerp-cron-worker script, it's currently in the process of being merged into 6.1, check the code https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-dev/openobject-server/6.1-here-comes-the-bogeyman-vmt

Edit2: meanwhile the openerp-cron-worker script has landed in lp:openobject-server/6.1 at rev4184 ( http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/6.1/revision/4184 )

Comment: I had already tried using the thu.openerp link but it was not working.

Comment: The site is working fine, both today and yesterday, perhaps a problem on your end ? Perhaps try the google cached version : http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QIDAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3AtAbJymzAN3kJ%3Athu.openerp.com%2Fopen-days-2012%2Fgunicorn.html%2B%26cd%3D1%26hl%3Dnl%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dbe&ei=_LazT4DEBuqR0AWhvtjPBQ&usg=AFQjCNHIeQeraz6M9xzCTlu-JNunfwy6Jg

Comment: What I meant is the instructions are not complete. I am going to meet the guys of openerp tomorrow and I will post my findings.

Comment: The instructions are not complete because the code itself is not finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the that it has poor document if you look at the Green Unicorn (gunicorn) configuration link  [gUnicorn config](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html) you will find lot of parameters can be used over the gunicron process and worker management e.g.

1) worker_connections
The maximum number of simultaneous clients. In that case you configuration file can configured like :

```
worker-connections = 1000
```

2) max_requests
The maximum number of requests a worker will process before restarting.

```
max_requests = 2
```

3) timeout
Workers silent for more than this many seconds are killed and restarted.

```
timeout = 30
```

For Security :

4) limit_request_line

The maximum size of HTTP request line in bytes.

```
limit_request_line = 4094
```

So you can configure your server configuration file using this params which will help you in better process managment.

Hope this will help you.
Let me know If I am missing something.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but this extra pointer may be helpful: there is an OpenERP [framework changes document](http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/openerp-61-framework-changes) describing the usage of Gunicorn. See pages 12-15.

Answer (score 0):

I guess smth has changed.

I don't see in 6.1.1 any code related to separate cron-worker script.

Moreover looks like [it was deleted](https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-dev/openobject-server/6.1-multicorn-al/+merge/109544).

Guys, anyone running OpenERP with Gunicorn in production? How do You handle cron issue?

Comment: You should better [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.